# find not passing mtime into ImageMagick

Tags: shell, imagemagick, cp

I have a terminal command

```
find "/Users/tcokimac/Desktop/find"  -size +2MB  -mtime +60 -exec convert "{}"  -resize 80% -quality 80%  /Users/tcokimac/Desktop/find/IMG_0096.JPG  -set filename:base "%[basename]" "/Users/tcokimac/Desktop/new/%[filename:base].jpg" \;
```

It is supposed to scan a directory of images more then 2MB and less then 60 days old and convert them into a new folder. But the scan results no images found

Solution found it was my coding, -mtime +60 is everything over 60 days, needed to change to -60 for all files under 60 days –

```
    find "/Users/tcokimac/Desktop/find"  -size +2MB  -mtime +60 -exec convert "{}"  -resize 80% -quality 80%  /Users/tcokimac/Desktop/find/IMG_0096.JPG  -set filename:base "%[basename]" "/Users/tcokimac/Desktop/new/%[filename:base].jpg" \;
```

Comment: Did you create the output directory first? Why is IMG_0096.jpg in the command?

Comment: Why do you think `mtime` is not being passed?

Comment: Please, can you share your `find -version` output and check actual modification time of files by `ls -lt`

Comment: found it. it was my coding, -mtime +60 is everything over 60 days, needed to change to -60 for all files under 60 days

Comment: @PeterFriedlander Glad you found it. You should post your solution as an answer rather than as a comment, so the question will be answered.